# Wordpress menu: Remove list-items and apply ".current-menu-item" to anchor tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

Title says it all.  In short, how to make `wp_nav_menu();` output this:

```
<nav>
    <a>Menu Item</a>
    <a class="current-menu-item">Menu Item</a>
    <a>Menu Item</a>
    <a>Menu Item</a>
    <a>Menu Item</a>
</nav>
```

I read this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-li-elements-from-output-of-wp_nav_menu/ which removes the unordered list and list-items.

But removing the `<li>`s also removes its useful `.current-menu-item` class when you're on that particular page. How to get that class to show up on the anchor tag instead?

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the output via the first parameter of the function `wp_nav_menu($args);`.

```
$args = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu($args);
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu for full documentation.

Comment: Why the downvote? I am trying to support and solve the problem and it is a valid answer.